# GraphQL returned error => [Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 500]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

Was hoping to get some assistance to what I'm running into. When I run a mutation on login/signup, there aren't any problems. Even when I try to run a fetch all post. I am instead getting this problem when I try to like a post as shown below.

**Frontend**

Here we use a mutation to create a new like. The token and post_id is passed (token => user_id)

```
export const createLike = gql`
    mutation like($token: String, $post_id: Int) {
        like(token: $token, post_id: $post_id) {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

Within the function, we call the like create once a person click on the heart button.

```
const [ like ] = useMutation(createLike);
const likePost = () => {
    like({ variables: { token, post_id } })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('THE RES WAS ', res);
            if (res.data.like) {
                dispatch(changePostLike(res.data.like));
            }
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log('THE ERROR WAS ', e));
};


<AntDesign
    onPress={() => likePost()}
    name="heart"
    size={40}
    color={isLiked ? 'red' : 'white'}
    style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end', marginTop: 20 }}
/>
```

I'm noticing that the backend never gets reached and clicking the heart automatically gives an error of 500. Did I miss spell something? I've read my code multiple times but can't find any problems with the approach.

Thank you for all the help on this one.

Comment: tokan as parameter, not by link/header? debug/explore network request details

Comment: @xadm I have it saved within the phone as a cookie? Before I make a query request I get it and send it to the backend. I have GraphQL for data and Redux for state management

Comment: @xadm Actually found the problem. When I was sending data to the backend it was sending the post_id as a string while it's expecting an integer instead. Really wish more information was provided instead of just a 500 error.

Comment: checked raw network response?

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/networking/authentication/#header ... use `onCompleted` useMutation option to get response (or 'data' returned from hook) https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/mutations/#options

Answer (score 1):

I came across a different post earlier regarding type being an issue. Although the code seemed to be correct, JS was converting an integer to a string. This resulted in the 500 error.

Careful not only types declaration but also what JS might be sending in the variables parameters.